# How to I save multiple values to the input tag?

Tags: html, jsp

How to select and update 10 records based on a field.In my HTML page  I've input tags for every row from the database. When I click on submit button I just get the value  of first row to the next page. The values of other rows  doesn't get submitted.

How can I pass the values of the 10 different records to the next page?

```
<% 
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
Connection  conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","yfr146",    "kas0"); 
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT *FROM (SELECT * FROM YFR146 ORDER BY CUSTOMER) t WHERE ROWNUM <=10"); 
int CUSTOMER,COCD,OWNCO,TOTAL_BALANCE,TOTAL,BEYOND_CREDIT,CREDIT_LIMIT=0; 
float RECON_ACCT=0; 
String  CUSTOMER_NAME,STT,SEARCH_TRM,AGEING,REMARK,GROUP_NAME,CCA,REDEFINED_ST,INTEREST,PAYMENT_TERMS="";
if(!rs.next()) 
{ 
    out.println("");
} 
else 
{ 
%> 
    <form action="SAVE.jsp" method="post"> 
      <table border="5" style="border-collapse: collapse"> 
      <tr>
        <th>Customer</th> <!-- columns left out for brevity -->
        <th>Total</th> 
        <th>Beyond Credit</th> 
     </tr> 
<% 
    do 
    { 
        CUSTOMER=rs.getInt("CUSTOMER");
        TOTAL=rs.getInt("TOTAL"); 
        BEYOND_CREDIT=rs.getInt("BEYOND_CREDIT"); 
%> 
        <tr> 
            <td><%=CUSTOMER%></td>  
            <td><input type="text" name="total"/></td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="beyond"/></td> 
         </tr> 
<% 
    }while(rs.next()); 
} 
%> 
</table> 
<center> <input type="submit" value="send"></center> 
</form>
```

Comment: since I've selected 10 records only and i want to update the values where I've added the input tag but when i click submit it just takes the  first value enter ... but i would know how to get multiple values to the next page

Comment: OK, Please pay attention and follow my advice: Fix your title so it no longer shout at us and make sure it covers your question. [ask] has some great guidance. Next [edit] your comment into the question. Make sure the indenting of your code looks ok. Explain clearly (with an example of 2 records) what your output is off this code and what the result is when submit the form.

Comment: The problem is that the `name` attribute on your inputs are not unique. You could try to add an record id to each attribute name, something like `total_1` but I'm not a jsp dev so maybe the framework offers functionality to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are only getting values of one row only.
First this is not advisory from my point of view using different input field with same name but with one button form action.

If you want to do that.

**Option 1**

Generate a unique name for ex create a count variable and concat to your fields name like

```
<% int count=1;%>    //outside the loop

<input type="text" name="name"<%=count++%>>  //inside the loop
```

In next page

```
<%

for(int i=1,i<=50;i++){

System.out.println("Name "+i+" is "+request.getParameter("name"+i));
}

%>
```

**Opton 2**

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

In other page

```
String[] name=request.getParameterValues("name");
```